# C# Connecting to mysql using linq VS OleDB

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, oledb

I'm developing a web application with ASP.net & C# and it needs to connect to mysql database.
I'm not sure if I should use linq or OleDB to connect to mysql!!!

can you give me some advices about that?

Comment: Object Relational Mapping (ORM). And I agree with Devtron, they are bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of options:

- http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/
- http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/
- http://www.alinq.org

Answer (score 0):

you can use either Entity Framework or NHibernate. Both support Linq.